# Foundation set wrong column width

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Sass version of Foundation 6. I'm having an annoying problem on the width of the columns that I never had before.

This is my simple HTML code

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="foo__row">
    <div class="foo__title">Lorem ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this the SCSS

```
.foo{
  &__row{
    @include grid-row;
  }
  &__title{
    @include grid-column(12);
  }
}
```

But the CSS set the width of `foo__title` at 150% instead 100%.

[image]

Does anyone know why? I'm going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!
I noticed there was a line declared as

```
@include grid-row(8);
```

So the grid system is based on 8 columns and not on 12 cols.

Answer (score 0):

what I can see you are including a mixin called: `grid-column(12)` into your class:

```
&__title{
    @include grid-column(12);
}
```

do a search in our project per: **grid-column(12)** and see what it is inside, I quite sure you gonna get in that mixin the result above.